# How to do broken scale in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to do a broken scale for a 2D scatterplot using tikzpicture, but I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Edit: I have found a way to do a broken scale. Here is what I have so far:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis line style = thick,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = 30, xmax = 250,
    ymin = 950, ymax = 1400,
    xtick distance = 50,
    ytick distance = 100,
    axis x discontinuity = crunch,
    axis y discontinuity = crunch,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 4,
    major tick style = {thick, black},
    major grid style = {gray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray},
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
    x label style={anchor=west, at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)}, xshift=10pt},
    ylabel style={anchor=south, at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)}, yshift=10pt},    
    width = 0.7\textwidth,
    height = 0.7\textwidth]  

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to have the grid to start from the minimum boundaries, i.e. from 50 for *x* and 1000 for *y*, like my previous picture above.

Comment: Please show some of your work, people are generally happy to adapt, amend and ameliorate, but pure "please do this for me" kind of postings are not as happily received.

Comment: In addition to what Ingmar mentioned, could you please edit your question to be more specific about what you'd like? Do you only want to change the min and max of the axes? (If so, you can simply do `ymin=1000, ymax=1400, xmin=50, xmax=250`.) Or are you looking specifically for a "break" symbol to be drawn on each axis, as in your image? Will any break symbol do, or does it specifically have to be that one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See [the `axis x discontinuity` (or `axis y discontinuity`) option provided by PGFPlots](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-axisdescription#sec-20.12).

Comment: @Ingmar apologies... I'm new to this, this is my first post ever.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you so much! That is what I was looking for! I'm somewhat happy with what I have at the moment, but I'm wondering if I can make it even better. I will edit my original post. So if it's okay with you, please have a look and let me know if it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default options for `axis x/y discontinuity` don't provide for slashes. But you can always manually draw things to the axes. In your case, I would probably make use of the `axis x/y line shift` option to shift the axes outwards first:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis line style = thick,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = 50, xmax = 250,
    ymin = 1000, ymax = 1400,
    xtick distance = 50,
    ytick distance = 100,
    grid = both,
    axis x line shift=0.75cm,
    axis y line shift=0.75cm,
    minor tick num = 4,
    major tick style = {thick, black},
    major grid style = {gray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray},
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    axis line style = {shorten > = -10pt},
    x label style = {anchor = west, at = {(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift = 10pt},
    y label style = {anchor = south, at = {(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift = 10pt},    
    width = 0.7\textwidth,
    height = 0.7\textwidth,
    clip=false]  

\draw[thick] 
    (xticklabel* cs:0) -- (xticklabel* cs:-0.05) coordinate (x gap right)
    (xticklabel* cs:-0.075) coordinate (x gap left) -- (xticklabel* cs:-0.175);
\draw[thick] 
    (yticklabel* cs:0) -- (yticklabel* cs:-0.05) coordinate (y gap right)
    (yticklabel* cs:-0.075) coordinate (y gap left) -- (yticklabel* cs:-0.175);
\draw[thick] 
    ([shift={(2.5pt,2.5pt)}]x gap right) -- ([shift={(-2.5pt,-2.5pt)}]x gap right)
    ([shift={(2.5pt,2.5pt)}]x gap left) -- ([shift={(-2.5pt,-2.5pt)}]x gap left);
\draw[thick] 
    ([shift={(2.5pt,2.5pt)}]y gap right) -- ([shift={(-2.5pt,-2.5pt)}]y gap right)
    ([shift={(2.5pt,2.5pt)}]y gap left) -- ([shift={(-2.5pt,-2.5pt)}]y gap left);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis line style = thick,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = 50, xmax = 250,
    ymin = 1000, ymax = 1400,
    xtick distance = 50,
    ytick distance = 100,
    grid = both,
    axis x line shift=0.75cm,
    axis y line shift=0.75cm,
    minor tick num = 4,
    major tick style = {thick, black},
    major grid style = {gray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray},
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    axis line style = {shorten > = -10pt},
    x label style = {anchor = west, at = {(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift = 10pt},
    y label style = {anchor = south, at = {(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift = 10pt},    
    width = 0.7\textwidth,
    height = 0.7\textwidth,
    clip=false]  

\draw[thick, decoration={zigzag}] 
    (xticklabel* cs:0) -- (xticklabel* cs:-0.025) decorate { -- (xticklabel* cs:-0.1) } -- (xticklabel* cs:-0.175);
\draw[thick, decoration={zigzag}] 
    (yticklabel* cs:0) -- (yticklabel* cs:-0.025) decorate { -- (yticklabel* cs:-0.1) } -- (yticklabel* cs:-0.175);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]